# Shopify node API get the latest products updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify

I'm currently looping my whole list of products I get from shopify and get the updated date of the object, is there a more optimized way to use it? does shopify have a resource to get the latest updated products so I can optimize my work

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you should be able to get a list of products filtering on three specific date fields ... `published_at_min`, `created_at_min` and the one you likely want, `updated_at_min`.

[https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-01/resources/product#[get]/admin/api/2022-01/products.json](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-01/resources/product#%5Bget%5D/admin/api/2022-01/products.json)

```
import Shopify from '@shopify/shopify-api';
const client = new Shopify.Clients.Rest('your-development-store.myshopify.com', accessToken);
const data = await client.get({
  path: 'products',
  query: {"updated_at_min":"2021-01-15T16:15:00-04:00"},
});
```

Add it to your query and go from there.